# twitter public_timeline giving duplicates

Tags: ruby, twitter

Im getting the last 20 tweets from twitter using the public_timeline function in ruby and Im giving at least 60 seconds between each call but im always getting duplicates of the previous call every second call. as a test i have given several minutes between each call but still every second call is a duplicate.
Has anyone heard of this occuring or have any ideas what im doing wrong?

Thanks

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely the Twitter API's cache being slow to update. Your code should be resistant to duplications regardless so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: yeah im guessing thats all it was. It was happening for afew days and i seen on twitter status that the stream was flagged with some faults. Its back working normally now and yeah the code is resistant to duplicates but was just curious if i was doing something wrong. thanks